# edit file by searching for pattern, store findings in var, modify var, write modified var to same file

Tags: regex, bash, file, sed, find

My programming is not efficient. Meaning, I could write a solution using bash program to accomplish what I am going to ask, but I wanted to see if there is a one liner that can accomplish the same thing. I've always had a hard time wrapping my head around how to order utilities such as sed and awk in order to get the desired results. I can use those utilities, but they are never advanced in they way I write them. Here is what I would like to accomplish.

I have dumped user objects from openldap into one flat file. So if you haven't seen what that looks like it, i provided a snip of one user fake object record.

```
dn: uid=steven.hawkin@science.com,ou=people,o=nasa
mail: steven.hawking@cambridge.com
mail: steven.hawking@science.com
uid: steven.hawking@science.com
homeDirectory: /home/hawkin
givenName: Steven
sn: hawkin
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
objectClass: LoginProperties
objectClass: Top
```

I'm migrating data from OpenLDAP to eDirectory in bulk in the short term until the IDM driver is setup to do this syncing regularly. This file has 17000+ objects within it, and each collections of attributes for each user (object) is separated by a space. 412 users objects have attributes related to a system login information such as homeDirectory, groupID, Shell, etc and some do not. Within the new eDirectory environment there is a objectClass called posixAccount which requires the attributes I mentioned, and one additional attribute which is not present called unquieID. What I would like to do is search this single file for ^homeDirectory: and in the case of the Steven Hawking example it would return homeDirectory: /home/hawkin and I would take the username hawkin from the end and convert it unquieID: hawkin and write it as a new line. So that every object that has the attribute homeDirectory: in the file will now be written to keep homeDirectory: /home/ and right underneath it would be unquieID: . so the new object will look like this:

```
dn: uid=steven.hawkin@science.com,ou=people,o=nasa
mail: steven.hawking@cambridge.com
mail: steven.hawking@science.com
uid: steven.hawking@science.com
homeDirectory: /home/hawkin
unquieID: hawkin
givenName: Steven
sn: hawkin
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
objectClass: LoginProperties
objectClass: Top
```

Based on my research, this would happen to 412 objects out of the 1700+ that are in the entire file. Of course I will also need to add objectClass: posixAccount to each of same 412 user objects, but I figured I could do this with a separate pass on the file like after the fact. Like this:

```
sed -i '/^unquieID: /a objectClass: posixAccount' $1
```

Of course if you want to throw adding "objectClass: posixAccount" on a new line at the same time as searching for homeDirectory and adding uniqueID, then by all means.

Remember, I can do this programaically using a inefficient bash program and iterate through each line in the file, but my goal here would be to learn how to do this will a one liner using any command or regex necessary.

Thanks

Comment: Try `sed -E '/^homeDirectory/{ s~.*/([^/]+)$~\0\nunquieID: \1~ }' file`

Comment: i got sed: invalid option -- 'E'. perhaps a sed version issue? I tried lowercase e and go the following: sed: -e expression #1, char 50: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: Then your sed doesn't support `-E` try using BRE syntax: `sed '/^homeDirectory/{ s~.*/\([^/]+\)$~\0\nunquieID: \1~ }' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^homeDirectory/ {n=split($NF,a,"/");u=a[n];o=1} 1; 
       u                {print "uniqueID:",u; u=""} 
       o&&/^objectClass/{print $1,"posixAccunt"; o=0}' file

dn: uid=steven.hawkin@science.com,ou=people,o=nasa
mail: steven.hawking@cambridge.com
mail: steven.hawking@science.com
uid: steven.hawking@science.com
homeDirectory: /home/hawkin
uniqueID: hawkin
givenName: Steven
sn: hawkin
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccunt
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
objectClass: LoginProperties
objectClass: Top
```

**Explanation**

search the key and create the uniqueID by splitting the last field by "/" and getting the last value, we also set two indicators, one is the uniqueId itself and the other is to flag the objectClass to be printed. `1` prints the current line.  If the `u` indicator is set; print it and reset.  If the `o` indicator is set and we entered the objectClass section print the additional item and reset that indicator.  Here the position is set to the second, but by changing where we print the current line it can be moved around.

Comment: wow. spot checked it and it looked like it worked. Could you talk me through the code so i can better understand? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Again, So i tried to take what you provided, and massage the string to conduct an additional change like this: 
  awk '/^uid/ {n=gsub("oldemail.com","newemail.com",$2);u=a[n];o=1} 1; ' $1
It does what I want it to do , but it prints it out the entire file twice. I'm assuming I need to fit this into the same command but not clear how to step into a different match on the uid pattern.